# Как решить ошибку: socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, сокет, websocket

код сервера

```
import socket
import time
import threading

name = []

def pol():
    while True:
        try:
            user, adress = server.accept()
            print("подключился",adress)
            user.setblocking(0)
            player.append(user)
            print(user)
        except:
            pass
   
def polu():
    while True:
        for x in player:
            try:
                msg = x.recv(1024)
                print(msg)
                msg = msg.decode()
                print(msg)
                sen(msg=msg, ot=x)
            except:
                pass

def sen(msg, ot):
    for x in player:
        if not x == ot:
            x.sendall(msg.encode())
        else:
            pass




server =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY,1)
host = socket.gethostbyname("192.168.0.29")
port = 50005
server.bind((host, port))
server.setblocking(0)
server.listen(10)
player = []
print("сервер активен")

v = threading.Thread(target=polu)
v.start()
t = threading.Thread(target=pol)
t.start()
print("localhost")
while True:
    n = input()
    if n == "q":
        print("сервер выключен")
        server.close()
        input()
        exit()
    for y in player:
        try:
            y.sendall(n.encode())
        except:
            player.remove(y)
            y.close()
        print(y)
    time.sleep(1)
```

код клиента

```
import socket
import threading
def prov():
    while True:
        msg = client.recv(1024)
        msg = msg.decode()
        print(msg)

client =  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(("62.217.189.249",50005))
try:
    client.connect_ex(("62.217.189.249",50005))
    print("всё ок")
except:
    print("сервер выключен")
    input()
    exit()
    input()
p = threading.Thread(target=prov)
p.start()
```

ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Danya998pop/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.connect(("62.217.189.249",50005))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

я пытаюсь cделать простой чат для меня и друзей в разных городах, посмотрел гайды cделал точь в точь но нечего не работает(задавайте вопросы в коментах добавлю нужную информацию)

Answer (score 0):

Я недавно смог найти возможность общаться с помощью библиотеки socket без локальной сети. Для этого нужно сделать переадресацию портов в настройках портов и для адреса сервера в коде сервера нужно использовать команду

```
socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
```

Как сделать переадресацию портов? В качестве имени службы используем IP, который дал [этот сайт](https://2ip.ru/), а в остальном всё понятно. Для клиента нужно использовать адрес имени службы с переадресации и выбранный порт. Не пугайся, что сервер работает на одном адресе, а клиенты подключаются с другого.

Вот мои рабочие коды:

```
import threading, socket, time
Address, Server = [socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 20081], socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Server.bind(tuple(Address))
print("Запущен сервер с адресом: " + ":".join([Address[0], str(Address[1])]))
Users, Ended = list(), False
def Joining():
    pass
    global Users, Server, Ended
    while not Ended:
        Ended = True
        Server.listen(1)
        User_Index, User_Address = Server.accept()
        User = {"User":User_Index, "Address":User_Address}
        print("Присоеденился пользователь с адресом: " + str(User["Address"]))
        del User_Index, User_Address
        Users.append(User)
        del User
        if Ended == True:
            time.sleep(1)
        if Ended == True:
            print("Остановлено.")
Joining = threading.Thread(target=Joining)
Joining.start()
while True:
    Ended = False
    for User in Users:
        User["User"].sendall(input("Напишите сообщение. >>> ").encode())
        Data = None
        while True:
            Data = User["User"].recv(1024).decode()
            if Data != None:
                break
        print("Пришло сообщение: " + Data)
        del Data
```

```
import socket, time
Server = socket.socket()
Host, Port = "Адрес имени службы", 20081
Server.connect((Host, Port))
print("Подключено!")
while True:
    Data = None
    while True:
        Data = Server.recv(1024).decode()
        if Data != None:
            break
    print("Пришло сообщение: " + Data)
    del Data
    Server.sendall(input("Напишите сообщение. >>> ").encode())
```

Comment: Можете пояснить как это работает пожалуйста.

Comment: И всё-же можете сказать почему неработает мой код?

Comment: Что именно нужно объяснить?

Comment: Ошибка в вопросе выводится если сервер выключен или не принимает подключения.

Comment: @kostta_200808 можете сказать как исправить мой код